# Java Web Project Class Path

Tags: spring, resources, classpath

I am using Eclipse Helios. I have a Dynamic Web Project.

I want to load a property file using Spring 3.1.0 for which I use the following configuration

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <value>classpath:resources/dc-config.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

This folder by name resources is present in WEB-INF/classes directory

But when I try to start my Tomcat 6 Server I get the following error

```
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name dc-config, locale en_US
```

Isin't my resources folder in the classpath as it is in the classes folder which in turn is in the classpath ?

Please let me know if I am missing something here

Comment: Have you tried naming your properties file dc-config_en_US.properties?

Comment: Yes I have tried it and that does not work either :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrong bean class maybe ?
Try this:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
 <property name="basenames">
   <list>
     <value>classpath:resources/dc-config</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: is the bean actually created by spring when you look at the logs ?

Comment: Hi I got it working. It turned out that my component was not getting scanned as a result of which my autowire was not working

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is a small typo. Try either

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location"> <!-- not locations -->
            <value>classpath:resources/dc-config.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

or

```
     <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:resources/dc-config.properties</value>
        </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```